# Rails 4.2.1, Using Collections With Partials Causes Items Displayed To Be Repeated Based On Number Of Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, partials, repeat

I'm running into a weird issue here. I'm running Rails 4.2.1 & I'm using the Rails Crash Course book by Anthony Lewis and am following the instructions outlined in the book. The link for the book instructions are [found here](https://books.google.com/books?id=niMBBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q&f=false) via Google Books.

So in the instructions he says to move the following code block into a partial called "_post.html.erb"

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

<h2><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>

<p><i><%= friendly_date post.created_at %></i></p>

<p><%= post.body %></p>

<p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>

<%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete,

        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

</p>

<% end %>
```

He then says that you can run the following code to basically activate the partial.

```
<%= render :partial => 'post', :collection => @posts %>

// or the simplified version ...

<%= render @posts %>
```

However when I do this, the items displayed on the page get repeated by the number of items.  So in this case, I have 3 items and they get repeated 3 times. [I have attached a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zk4z.png)

However when the code is not removed into a partial and no collections are being used, then it works fine. In other words, having the code inside the view's "index.html.erb" file, there are no repetitions of the items being displayed.

Can anyone help me out with what is going on here? I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

For each `post` Rails is running partial code, where you iterate over all posts, thus you get repeats!

Take out the iteration from your partial and you should be fine. Rails automatically assigns local variable `post` in your partial when you use `render` with collection.

```
<h2><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>

<p><i><%= friendly_date post.created_at %></i></p>

<p><%= post.body %></p>

<p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>

<%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete,

        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

</p>
```

Comment: You should either use `<%= render :partial => 'post', :collection => @posts %>` or `<% @posts.each do |post| %>`, but not both

Comment: Sorry but can you elaborate on this. Having just the block that start with `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` works in the index.html.erb file. If I was to use `<%= render :partial => 'post', :collection => @posts %>` how would that work out? Thanks

Comment: thanks for you help, I just figured it out thanks to your and the other commenter helping out !!

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%= render @posts %>
```

if you do this @posts is already a collections of posts therefore you do not need to iterate again, just erase this part:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: that ends up removing all the posts being listed from the page

Comment: actually sorry about that, tried it again and it works this time

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like this issue got resolved. I had misread the paragraph and was duplicating the code as pointed out by @petr and @marv-c The correct solution was to move the code inside the block to the partial file

```
<h2><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>

<p><i><%= friendly_date post.created_at %></i></p>

<p><%= post.body %></p>

<p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>

<%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete,

    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

</p>
```

Then remove the code for the block `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` and `<%-# end %>` Now I can add in the collection code `<%= render @posts %>`where the block was originally

Once again, thanks to @petr and @marv-c for helping out!!